# How to manage this JWT?

Tags: javascript

I manage the client side javascript and must do a POST call to a server with api JWT.

```
claims = ""
token = ""
```

with also the Bearer.. he has given to me the bearer.

I want to know if I must generate a specific JWT side client or no?

Comment: the string eyJ0ex.... is your jwt. You need to send it back when you make a request.

Answer (score 3):

i think you misunderstood how JWT is supposed to work, you cannot generate a JWT from a client-side app.
What keeps it secure is a private key held only by the server, that is used to sign the token.

So, by design your client app is supposed to retrieve a JWT (e.g. in exchange of a login/password).
Then the client app sends the JWT with each request to prove that it is authenticated.

Comment: in your client app's Javascript, you just add the header `Authorization: Bearer your_JWT` for each request to your server.
your client app doesn't need to check the JWT

Comment: the description of your server isn't very precise.
usually, the server only creates a JWT once. Later in you app, when you include the JWT in the Authorization header, it is used by the server to identify you, and do whatever the server is supposed to do